# Implementing Joins in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a plSql conversion to Spark.

1. In the plSql script there is a table: baseTable created with 5
   columns: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k.   The next step in the
   script is inserting the data into the baseTable but only into the
   columns: a, b, c, d
2. There is an update query: update1 in the script that inserts the
   data into the columns: e, f from another table: table1 by performing
       join with baseTable.
3. In the same way columns: g, h, i are updated using query: update2 from table2 and columns: j, k using query: update3 from
       table3.

Now I have data in all the columns in the table: baseTable

Here's how I performed joins in the spark code:

1. Created a dataframe for the step1 from plSql script with cols: a, b,
   c, d. Named it as df1
2. Created another dataframe for the query: update1 and joined it with df1. (Type of join used: left_join and df1 is on the left).
       Lets say the resultant table name is: "res1"
3. Created a dataframe for the query: update2 and joined it with res1. (Type of join used: left_join and res1 is on the left).
           Resultant is named as "res2"
4. Created a dataframe for the query: update3 and joined it with res2. (Type of join used: left_join and res2 is on the left).
               Resultant is named as "res3"
5. res3.createOrReplaceTempView("baseTable")

The joins I performed in spark are giving me correct data but the job is taking lot of time to complete.
Technically I did the same operation from plSql script. Is it an expensive join if I follow the same way from the script ?
If there is any other join that could make it faster, could anyone let me know.

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried? It will be helpful for other to quickly identify the issue.

Comment: Each query has nearly 150 columns and would be confusing to relate. That was the reason I just gave it in a  description. But if you still want me to post it, I'll try to do that.